# Usage of "Subtitle"

Tags: phrase-request

In a software application, I generate a video in which a text is shown. As an option, the text can be read by text-to-speech technique. To ease tracking the spoken text by the user, I have provided an option by which the spoken word is shown in a bar at the bottom of the video. I use a check box for this option, but what can I call this option?

- Show subtitles
- Subtitle the spoken word
- ....

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a checkbox, you don't actually need the verb even. If the box is checked, that is interpreted as "on," and if it isn't, then it is interpreted as "off." So you could just have

> Subtitles

[image]
That looks fine to me.

If you really want the verb there, "**Show subtitles**" works well as well. "Subtitle the spoken word" is much too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Just one word, "Subtitles," will suffice.

You should never use text-to-speech in videos. It's the stupidest thing ever.

Comment: why not?! anyway it helps EFL learners to distinguish the pronunciation of the words, and ease reading a text. Isn't text-to-speech for that?

Comment: @Ahmad: Socializing is good. I don't know what text-to-speech is for. It's horrible. They've been trying to improve it for several decades now. The results are before us. You reason like a child. For pronunciation, check out the sound button positioned one-eighth of an inch east of each word in any online dictionary. It works. Believe me, it does.

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't get "Socializing is good" though.